# DJango - My forms.py elements are not showing up in the html template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am a newbie for Django and working on a project. I am stucked with setting up a forms.py and integrate the same with my template. I did all the required things with the help of all sort of tutorial I got online but I was unable to see the fields I declared in form on the HTML Page. Below is the code I used for each of the module. It would be great if anyone can help me out with this.

## **models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class EarlyBirds(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contact_number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.name, self.email)
```

## **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from .forms import EarlyBirdsForm

from .models import EarlyBirds

def register(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    success=''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EarlyBirdsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get('name','')
            email = request.POST.get('email','')
            number = request.POST.get('number','')
            if email:
                email_exist = EarlyBirds.objects.filter(email=email)
                if email_exist:
                    success = 'Thankyou for your intrest! This email is already registered with us. We will get back to you soon.'
                else:
                    eb_obj = EarlyBirds(name=name,email=email,contact_number=number)
                    eb_obj.save()
                    success = 'Thankyou for your intrest! We will get back to you soon.'
            else:
                success = 'Please fill out the required fields'
        else:
            success = form.errors
    else:
        form = EarlyBirdsForm()
    return render_to_response('ComingSoon.html', {'success':success}, context)
```

## **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from app_name.models import EarlyBirds

class EarlyBirdsForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=100)
    email = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=100)
    number = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = EarlyBirds
        fields = ("name", "email", "number")
```

## **template**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body align="center">
<form method="POST" action="{%url 'comingsoon:register'%}">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="header-blog-comingSoon" align="center">
    <!--<form method="post">

        <span>{{ form.as_p }}</span>    
        <br/>    

        <span><button class="comingsoon-Reg" type="submit">Register</button></span>
        <br/><br/>

        <br/><label class="successLabel">{{success}}</label>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## **project.urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ComingSoon/', include('app_name.urls', namespace="comingsoon")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

When I try to execute this code, the all I was able to see in the "Register" button on my html page. The three text fields for Name, Email and Contact number were missing. Please let me know what I am missing over here.

Comment: Seems like your not passing the form to your context: `{'sucess': success, 'form': form}`

Comment: You also have a comment tag (`<!--`) in your template, but if that were the problem you shouldn't even see the Register button, so maybe it's just what César said.

Comment: Thanks alot César, It worked..!!
I was damn sure that it will be some silly thing I would have missed. You can add your comment as the answer so that I can upvote.

Comment: you cant upvote http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up =) only accept for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the form to your context:

```
def register(request):
    ...
    return render_to_response('ComingSoon.html', {'success':success, 'form': form}, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try writing your form like this:

```
class EarlyBirdsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EarlyBirds
        fields = '__all__'
```

Much easier and simpler. Since you're using all the attributes in the model, might as well connect the form directly with the model.

And César Bustíos said it right. You didn't add the form in the context dictionary for your template.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sentient. I will surely use this in my project.

And yes César Bustíos solution worked :)